# MySQL - count in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, sum

I have the following table:

```
+----+---------------------+---------------+
| id |     created_at      | deklaracja_id |
+----+---------------------+---------------+
|  1 | 2015-01-09 12:14:00 |             1 |/*deklaracja*/
|  2 | 2015-02-09 12:14:00 |             1 |/*korekta for 1*/
|  3 | 2015-03-09 12:14:00 |             3 |/*deklaracja/
|  4 | 2015-01-09 12:14:00 |             3 |/*korekta for 3*/
|  5 | 2015-10-09 12:14:00 |             3 |/*korekta for 3*/
|  6 | 2015-10-09 12:14:00 |             6 |/*deklaracja*/
+----+---------------------+---------------+
```

Cond:
id = deklaracja_id is "deklaracja"
id <> deklaracja_id is "korekta"

I need a query to show all "deklaracja" and count of their "korekty" later than 2015-01-09.

```
Ex.
+----+---------------------+---------------+
| id |     created_at      | korekty_count |
+----+---------------------+---------------+
|  1 | 2015-01-09 12:14:00 |             1 |
|  3 | 2015-03-09 12:14:00 |             2 |
|  6 | 2015-10-09 12:14:00 |             0 |
+----+---------------------+---------------+
```

I've tried something like:

```
SELECT *, 
SUM(CASE WHEN (id <> deklaracja_id)THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
AS korekty_count 
FROM Deklaracja 
WHERE created >= '2015-09-01 00:00:00'
```

but it's not working and now I'm totally stuck :/

Comment: @Strawberry because the column id `is equal to` the column deklaracja_id at those records.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `GROUP BY` clause to your query.

```
SELECT *, 
SUM(CASE WHEN (id <> deklaracja_id)THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
AS korekty_count 
FROM Deklaracja 
WHERE created_at >= '2015-01-09 00:00:00' GROUP BY deklaracja_id
```

Comment: I don't think that quite works.  Move the date condition inside the CASE test.

Comment: According to the result he said he expects, I managed to get that result from this query.

Comment: The stated condition is to "show all "deklaracja" and count of their "korekty" later than 2015-01-09."  I take that to mean show (all deklaracja) with (count of their korekty later than 2015-01-09).  If the OP meant show all (deklaracja later than 2015-01-09) with (count of their korekty), then you're correct.

Comment: You are using a MySQL extension to `GROUP BY` that allows for non-aggregated fields to appear in the `SELECT` clause. The values of these non-aggregated fields, i.e `id`, `created_at` in your case,  are [indeterminate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html). Hence, the result from your query is non-deterministic.

Comment: All I did was look a his output ex. provided in the question (where he says he wants the records 1, 3 and 6 and their counts of "korekty". According to his model, there will be only 1 record in which the `id = deklaracja_id` and the rest will be `korekty` of the given id. By grouping by `deklaracja_id`, I'm taking only the the records in which `id = dekaracja_id`.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu You are grouping by `deklaracja_id`, then do a `SELECT *`. According to the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) either `id=1`, or `id=2` can be returned for  `deklaracja_id=1`. Hence, you might get the correct result, but you also might not.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos here is a copy of your sqlfiddle with my query. It works exactly like OP wanted. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61269/14/0

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu Well, I tried to explain as best as I could the reason why the result you get *happens* to be the correct one. Depending on the table indices, query cache, etc. you also might get a completely different result on some other server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT id, created_at,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM Deklaracja AS t2
       WHERE t1.id = t2.deklaracja_id AND 
             t2.id <> t2.deklaracja_id) AS AS korekty_count
FROM Deklaracja AS t1
WHERE id = deklaracja_id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61269/3)

Comment: Need to add the date condition.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
  select id, created_at,
     ( select count(*) from deklaracja dt
       where dt.deklaracja_id <> dt.id
        and dt.deklaracja_id = d.deklaracja_id
        and dt.created_at >= '2015-09-01 00:00:00' ) as korekty_count
  from deklaracja d
  where id = deklaracja_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a subquery to get the records you're interested in before grouping:

```
SELECT
    id,
    created_at,
    COUNT(deklaracja_id) AS korekty_count
    FROM (
        SELECT id, deklaracja_id, created_at
        FROM Deklaracja 
        WHERE created_at >= '2015-09-01 00:00:00'
        AND id <> deklaracja_id
    ) tmp
    GROUP BY id;
```

[**See demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d959/1/0)

Comment: Why are you summing the IDs instead of counting them??

Comment: That's what I inferred the OP wanted based on the query he gave, but I think you're right -- I should be counting. I don't know what the table names mean so it's hard to say if that makes sense in context.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT created_at, count(*)-1
from Deklaracje d
where id in (select id from Deklaracje e
             where e.deklaracja_id=d.deklaracja_id)
group by deklaracja_id
```

[SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/713f9/8/0)

Comment: You're assuming there's exactly one non-korekty.  We don't know if that's valid.  And why use a subquery instead of doing the equality comparison directly?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [Giorgos Betsos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33103528/3215948) is a good one. However, if you want to achieve the same results without a sub-query like you tried in your query, then try this one using joins:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.created_at, COUNT(t2.id) AS korekty_count
FROM Deklaracja AS t1
LEFT JOIN Deklaracja AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.deklaracja_id
                           AND t2.id <> t2.deklaracja_id
WHERE t1.id = t1.deklaracja_id
  AND t1.created_at >= '2015-09-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07cfa/9)